# Is it generally a good idea to use as little registers as possible?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

[This is my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egAvz.png)

I'm writing as program in x86 assembly that calculates the average of four grades. I'm currently using four registers (`RAX`, `RBX`, `RCX` and `RDX`) to hold the four grades, which are declared in my `.data` section. I also have `quot`, `rem`, `total`, and `ans` all initialized to 0.

My general approach to this is to add the four registers together and store the total in the `total` variable. I was originally going to just keep the total in `RAX`, but then I thought to store it in a variable so I can reuse `RAX` and `RDX`.

Is this a good idea or am I just generating more code for myself? I reset the `RAX` and `RDX` registers to 0 so that I can use them for my division calculation (total / 4). The book I'm following is using the `RAX` and `RDX` registers, so I thought that's what I was supposed to do.

The code isn't finished, so ignored the `IDIV` at the last line.

```
segment .data
    a       dq  100
    b       dq  57
    c       dq  74
    d       dq  23
    quot    dq  0
    rem     dq  0
    total   dq  0
    ans     dq  0

segment .text
    global main

main:
    mov rax, [a]
    mov rbx, [b]
    mov rcx, [c]
    mov rdx, [d]

    add rax, rbx
    add rcx, rdx
    add rax, rcx
    mov [total], rax
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdx, 0
    mov rax, [total]
    mov rdx, 0
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please put your code in the question instead of linking to it, per site rules.

Comment: @EliSadoff sorry, it was just hard to type in the assembly code because of the spacing I was using. I'll work on doing that now.

Comment: Just copy and paste, don't type. That's a serious mistake many people do and make a non-reproducible problem here

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc  Only reason I couldn't initially copy and paste it was because I'm doing this in windows using putty to connect to my ubuntu account. I just typed it out on notepad and transferred it over. Got it working, though. I was unaware of the no pictures policy.

Comment: It's still easy to copy between Ubuntu and Windows via ssh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally performance-wise it is good idea to not access memory (especially memory outside of L0 cache) at all.

If you have spare register, it's cheaper to store value temporarily into it, than storing it into memory (although that write will be cached and next read will use that very likely, so it will not hurt that much as reading some "new" memory location). Also push/pop (stack) is memory, so storing value into spare register is also cheaper than temporary storage on stack.

Then again the fewer registers you clobber with your algorithm, the fewer you have to save/restore when you call that code from somewhere else, where you already have values in registers, so being resourceful and use only as few registers as possible is good idea.

---

About your source:

In your code the whole triplet of  `mov [total],rax`, `mov rax,0` and `mov rax,[total]` toward end can be reduced to only first instruction, which will update "total" memory. Then you load `rax` with zero, and then you load it with previous total value, ie. removing those two will just keep the total value in `rax` untouched.

But I would go even further and save more registers and wasteful instructions, like this:

```
mov   rax, [a]
add   rax, [b]
add   rax, [c]
add   rax, [d]
; rax = total (can overflow for large a/b/c/d)
```

division - signed variant

```
mov   [total], rax   ; can be omitted, if you don't need [total] updated
cqo                  ; sign-extend rax into rdx:rax
; ^ your "mov rdx,0" is bug, as you want "idiv", total of 4x -1 is -4 => rdx should be -1
mov   rcx,4
idiv  rcx

; only rax, rdx and rcx are modified, [rax, rdx] contains result
```

division - unsigned variant (when a, b, c, d are positive, or at least "total" is)

```
mov   [total], rax   ; can be omitted, if you don't need [total] updated
; calculate remainder after division by 4 by copying low 2 bits of "total" into rdx
mov   edx,eax        ; 32b mov clears upper 32b of rdx!
and   edx,3          ; bit 0 and bit 1 of total is remainder after unsigned /4
; calculate quotient of usigned rax/4 (by shifting rax two bits right)
shr   rax,2

; only rax, and rdx are modified, [rax, rdx] contains result
```

Comment: *the fewer registers you clobber with your algorithm, the fewer you have to save/restore*: The OP is talking about spilling to memory before even running out of call-clobbered registers (like RAX).  The choice is obvious there: just use them.  But in the situation you mention, it's often a choice between saving/restoring a call-preserved register, spilling your own data, or using an extra MOV reg,reg or two to reuse registers.  Spilling your own data is usually the worst, esp. if it's on the critical path for latency.

Comment: Signed division by 4 is best done with shifts, using SAR and correcting the "rounding" with SHR+stuff.  It's unfortunately a lot more complex than for division by two, but [clang and icc](https://godbolt.org/g/P1ZZ2H) both make good code (gcc uses cmov :/).  Anyway, since the OP's use-case (grades) means the numbers are non-negative, you should really just recommend treating them as unsigned and using SHR and AND.  At least put the crappy IDIV way last, and point out that it sucks.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't a right or wrong, unless you artificially limit yourself to fewer registers than are available, then you'd be adding opcodes and bloating your code. Use only the number of registers needed to encode the operations.

However, consider what will happen if the requirements change and you have to handle 100 grades. Or 1000. Or N.. That might inspire you to implement your logic differently.  Perhaps consider using the stack to store grades?

PS: From an architectural point of view, your main concern here is balancing caching and opcode overhead of spilling/restoring registers. That decision doesn't really apply here because any number of registers you spill (coding by hand) should be in the L1 cache. Really comes down to the point when your implementation runs out of registers and you start having to add spill opcodes.

Comment: We actually haven't done anything with stacks quite yet. We're just learning basic arithmetic right now. Thanks for the answer.